# Is nested GET possible in Redis?

Tags: redis

The basic setup is this:

```
SET foo bar
SET baz foo
```

Is something like this possible in a single statement?

```
GET GET baz
"bar"
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

While you can't do that with the Redis Strings, that's doable if you keep a Hash with all your "keys" and "values" instead. For example:

```
HSET miniredis foo bar
HSET miniredis baz foo
```

Now, to fetch the goods, you'll need Lua but since everything is bundled in a single data structure, it will be cluster-safe (at the expense of scalability).

```
EVAL "return redis.call('HGET', KEYS[1], redis.call('HGET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]))" 1 miniredis baz
```

Of course, this only works when there's always a single dereference level. Another peculiarity is the ability to self reference (i.e.g. `HSET miniredis minime minime`). These should be handled if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it using basic redis API.

I can see two options for you:

- do it yourself in whatever programming language you're using with redis;
- do it with a [lua script](http://redis.io/commands/EVAL).

Here is a very simple lua script example, doing what you want:

```
eval "return redis.call('get', redis.call('get', KEYS[1]))" 1 baz
```

**N.B.:** You can only use this script with standalone redis installation, because it's using keys that aren't explicitly declared via the `KEYS` array, so it's not cluster-safe (thanx to **Itamar Haber**'s comment).

Comment: > do it with a lua script - don't. You're accessing keys that aren't explicitly declared via the `KEYS` array, and that's not cluster-safe.

Comment: ;) Adding a Lua based answer that should do it